# Keras: Calculating loss as *median* across datapoints instead of mean

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, keras

The [Keras losses](https://keras.io/losses/) page says that if we have a custom loss function, then "the actual optimized objective is the mean of the output array across all datapoints." Is there any way we can optimize the *median* of the output array across all datapoints (instead of the mean)?

Comment: The median is not differentiable.

Comment: Even then, can't we do backpropagation by going back through the 'middle' point alone?

Comment: I am trying to do the same. I think we can penalize big losses with some coefficient. And then mean will be close to the median. But how to calculate that coef that is another math question. Currently, I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this, you would need to go down to tensorflow level

```
import keras
import tensorflow


def pick_median(arg_tensor):
    the_upper_tensor = tensorflow.contrib.distributions.percentile(arg_tensor, 50, interpolation='higher')
    the_lower_tensor = tensorflow.contrib.distributions.percentile(arg_tensor, 50, interpolation='lower')

    final_tensor = (the_upper_tensor + the_lower_tensor) / 2
    # print(the_count.eval(session=keras.backend.get_session()))

    return final_tensor
```

Here is how you would define, let's say, `median_squared_error` loss function:

```
def median_squared_error(arg_y_true,
                         arg_y_pred):
    final_tensor = keras.backend.square(arg_y_pred - arg_y_true)
    final_tensor = pick_median(arg_tensor=final_tensor)
    return final_tensor
```

Comment: I can't see how this works or what you are calculating. The final_tensor appears to be a scalar with shape () (in the case the y_true and y_pred are (`*`,1) tensors, whereas what is required is a tensor with shape (`*`,)